# How to set auth token in cookies in Safari Private mode?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, cookies, safari

I have an Angular1 app with token based authorization. I want to save auth token in cookies or Local/SessionStorage, but when I want to do it in Safari Private mode, "Quota Exceed" exception raises.
I checked Github and Twitter in Safari Private mode and they successfully set tokens in cookies. How did they do it? At backend? If so, how to do it with PHP?

Comment: Struggling to resolve this issue in a mode which will not preserve the cookie anyway seems like a waste of time.

Comment: @apokryfos If someone (e.g. Github) can do it, I want to do it too

Comment: Are you sure that Github uses the local storage sucesfully in safari private browsing?

Comment: @apokryfos They use only cookies in Private mode. You can check it with devtools

Comment: Cookies should work. `Quota Exceed` is raised when trying to use local storage. Try using `setcookie` in PHP if JavaScript doesn't work.

Comment: @apokryfos Ok, but will this cookie automatically set to browser?

Comment: `setcookie` will make that cookie due to be transmitted to the browser. The browser *should* set it, even if it is just for that request.